# Excel formula with dynamic variable based on input from whatever is in column of specific row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So, I have no idea if this is possible and my head is breaking.

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to track my plants. Let's say I have broccoli, peppers, plant x, plant y, and plant z. They each have different germination times. In this case, let's say broccoli takes 7 days to germinate (Sow date+7) and peppers take 14 (sowdate+14) and x y and z are just there to take up space for context and will have their very own number of days.

Since I sow on different dates, for instance, on 01.01.2022, I sow 1 seed of each plant. Then I enter the date I sowed it. Then on 08.01.2022, I sow another seed of broccoli and a plant z. Each plant is an individual entity that I want to track, each with its own SOW DATE. Then further down the line, I will have plant 32 (after having planted a bunch of different plants in the meantime) is another broccoli on 15.03.2022. So, plant 1, plant 6, plant 9 and plant 32 are all individual broccoli instances, each with different SOW DATES.

[Sheet one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilzdv.png)

I am currently using `=IF(Sheet1!B2<>"",Sheet1!B2+7)` as the rule for, in this case, broccoli. The problem is, the B2 will change as I enter each plant. I do not want to have to copy and paste the formula every time I add a plant. I want Excel to say "hey, you entered broccoli in row 32, so I am going to pull use the "broccoli formula (which is `SOWDATE+7`)".

To get the formula, I am using a simple Vlookup (`=VLOOKUP(A13,Sheet2!A1:B9,2,FALSE)`)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsaMs.png)

That explained...here is the problem. I need the "broccoli formula" to not use a static value like a cell number, but to grab the date (which is one cell to the right of the plant name) and use THAT and add 7. So instead of "B2" as my "SOWDATE", I need it to look one cell to the right and use that. Is there any way to do that?

Here are my screenshots and a link to the file [link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dswcqa2m9b3r5z/sample%20plant%20tracker.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Change the values in B column of sheet 2 just to be the number of days, eg 7. Then the germination date formula is =B2+VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,TRUE)

Comment: I KNEW when I finally got the answer it would be so obvious and stupid and simple!! I am sure you were thinking "what an idiot!". But when you are stuck in a logic loop and can't get out, you gotta ask for help. So THANK YOU SO MUCH!! It totally worked! Virtual hugs and kisses to you!!!

Comment: Saulysw: This is still the same file, but new problem and I thought I would ask it here. If I need to create a new post, I will. But here we go. If cell A1 says "Bell/Chili" or "Bell Chili" and I want to search B:B based on whether it finds Bell or chili, and total them under C3  easy. BUT, what if I don't want to specify "bell" and "chili", I just want to say "sum if you find any of the words in A1 in the list in B:B? So I can copy and paste for another plant species that has several subspecies that will contain part of A1 but not ALL of A1 without having to enter them all in the formula?

Comment: Probably better to post a new question. In brief, it would be easier to put multiple search terms in seperate cells and do multiple lookups with each cell. Note you can use wildcards with VLOOKUP e.g. `*bell*`

Answer (score 0):

```
=B2+CHOOSE(MATCH(A2,{"broccoli","germinate","peppers"},0),7,7,14)
```

in Sheet1,C2 should do.

idea : use match() & choose() function to select + values
catch : it is space n caps sensitive

alternative : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match learn a bit, benefit a (whole) lot.